# MS.Excel unfiltered cells deleted along with filtered cells

Tags: excel, filter

I have problem with my excel filter. Lets says I have this table:

[image: Full data before filtere]

and then I filtered "Chrono Cross" only

[image: Filtered data "Chrono Cross"]

.and then I delete the filtered data column C

[image: Delete filtered columns]

It should be ONLY deleted the filtered cells, but instead the result was like this:
[image]

My excel has a default setting from the installation.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Do you have a [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) or [Workbook_SheetChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196611.aspx) event macro in that workbook that could be affecting behavior?

Comment: Nope, it was newly created spreadsheet. And I just installed my MS.Office, so it's default setting and not linked to any other files or sheet